# Find cell in which named range is defined in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-named-ranges

In Google Sheet it's possible to use named ranges to give names to cells, for instance I can call cell A1 as "mass", and reference it in future formulas.

After a while I often forget in which cell I defined the named range. Is there an easy way to retrieve the original cell?

The best I found so far is Right Click --> Define the Named Range --> Use the search function of the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the **name box** at the left edge of the formula bar and enter any part of the name of the named range to see which sheet it is in. Click a range name in the drop-down list below to go to the named range.